# Laravel parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I developed a `laravel` application back in `August` this year, and it was working fine then. I am trying to run that application now, and it returns this error:

> parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or
>   T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in D:\bkonme\artisan line 31

And line 31 is like this:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
```

My `PHP` version is `5.6.14` and I am using `XAMPP` on `windows` platform. I have some idea of it happening because of some version conflict between `laravel` and `PHP`, but i don't know how to resolve that issue, any help?

Comment: install a fresh piece of laravel and put ur controller, model etc there  mybe will work not sure just idea.

Comment: can you show a bit more code before line 31? You probably have forgotten to close a tag or write a Semicolon *;*

Comment: This is going to be a hell lot of work to do, i want some simple solution!

Comment: I don't see how this should be connected to some version. `class` is a reserved word in php. It cannot be used as valid identifier for some property or similar.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are running php 5.6? @arkascha available from 5.5 up: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name

Comment: @lino This file is of laravel framework, i didn't write it. There is some problem with `::class`, and i m not sure, why is that so, because the same code was working fine earlier in august this year.

Comment: @Steve yes, I am 100% sure about this.

Comment: Are you using console? did you check your php version in console? Sometimes server php vesion is not the same you can use in console. just type "php -v"

Comment: well the error suggests otherwise, @maztch may be onto something

Comment: Exactly how do you try to "run" the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you have PHP/5.6.14 installed, your app is definitively not using it. You could not use `class` as identifier until PHP/5.5 ([demo](https://3v4l.org/AmumI)).

The feature is called *Class name resolution via ::class* and it's described in the [Migrating from PHP 5.4.x to PHP 5.5.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name) chapter of the PHP manual.

Comment: Well, yes, you are right, i checked my PHP version through CMD and it came out to be 5.4, coz another instance of XAMPP was installed and the path of that instance was added in the path variables, Thanks Mate!